# If $d_1$ and $d_2$ are two equivalent metric on $X$ then is $X$ complete with respect $d_1$ if and only if it is complete with respect $d_2$?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, examples-counterexamples, cauchy-sequences, complete-spaces

I know that completeness is not a topological property so that if $d_1$ and $d_2$ are two equivalent metric of $X$ then I can state that $X$ is complete with respect $d_1$ if and only if it is complete with respect $d_2$ by the homomorphy of $(X,d_1)$ and $(X,d_2)$ via the identity map. However if $\cal T_1$ and $\cal T_2$ are two equal topology on $X$ then a sequence converges with respect one of theese if and only if it converges with respect the each other (right?) so that I can conclude that a Cauchy sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\omega}$ converges with respect $d_1$ if and only if it converges with respect $d_2$ so that finally $X$ is complete with respect $d_1$ if and only if it is complete with respect $d_2$.

So first of all I ask if the statement is true and so if it is true then I ask if the argumentation I gave are correct; whereas if the result is not true then I ask a counterexample: could someone help me, please?

Comment: While the notion of a convergent sequence does not depend on the choice of (equivalent) metrics, the notion of Cauchy sequence does. Therefore, your overall argument does not fly.

Comment: @PhoemueX Okay, so is the statement true? if not, do you know a counterexample?

Comment: If $X$ is metrizable and compact then every metric for $X$ is complete. That is not hard. The converse: If $X$ is metrizable and non-compact then $X$ has an incomplete metric, is true, but quite hard. BTW, some non-compact metrizable spaces  (e.g. $\Bbb R$ ) do also have complete metrics, but some (e.g.$\Bbb Q$) do not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not true.

If we endow all subspaces of $\mathbb R$ with the Euclidean metric $d_e(x,y) = \lvert x - y \rvert$ (which means that they receive their standard topology), then $(\mathbb R,d_e) $ is complete, but $((0,\infty),d_e)$ is not.

The exponential map $\exp : \mathbb R \to (0,\infty)$ is a homeomorphism. Define a metric $d$ on $(0,\infty)$ by $d(x,y)= \lvert \exp(x)- \exp(y) \rvert$. Since $\exp$ is a homeomorphism, the metric $d$ induces the standard topology on $\mathbb R$ which means that $d$ is equivalent to $d_e$. However, the metric space $(\mathbb R, d)$ is not complete. In fact, the sequence $x_n = -n$ is a Cauchy sequence because with $r = \min(n,m)$ we get
$$d(x_n,x_m) = \lvert \exp(-n)- \exp(-m) \rvert = \lvert e^{-n}- e^{-m} \rvert = e^{-r}\lvert e^{-n+r}- e^{-m+r} \rvert \\ \le e^{-r}(e^{-n+r}+ e^{-m+r}) \le 2 e^{-r} .$$
But obviously $(x_n)$ does not converge to any $\xi \in \mathbb R$.

**Update:**

The equivalence of $d$ and $d_e$ follows from the following general observation:

- Let $(X_1,d_1)$ and $(X_2,d_2)$ be metric spaces with metric topologies $\tau_1, \tau_2$ and let $h : (X_1,\tau_1) \to (X_2,\tau_2)$ be a homeomorphism. Then $d'_1(x,y) = d_2(h(x),h(y))$ defines a metric on $d'_1$ on $X_1$ which is equivalent to $d_1$.

That $d'_2$ is a metric is easily verified (the proof works for any injective, not necessarily continuous, function $h : X_1 \to X_2$). The function $h$ is by definition an isometry $h :(X_1,d'_1) \to (X_2,d_2)$, in particular a homeomorphism $h : (X_1, \tau'_1) \to (X_2,\tau_2)$. This shows that
$$id = h^{-1} \circ h : (X_1, \tau_1) \stackrel{h}{\to} (X_2,\tau_2) \stackrel{h^{-1}}{\to} (X_1, \tau'_1)$$
is a homeomorphism which means that $\tau_1 = \tau'_1$.

Let us next observe

- If $(X_1,d'_1)$ is complete iff $(X_2,d_2)$ is complete.

This is obvious because $h$ is an isometry $h :(X_1,d'_1) \to (X_2,d_2)$.

In my example the metric space $((0,\infty),d_e)$ is not complete since each sequence $(\xi_n)$ in $(0,\infty)$ converging to $0$ when regarded as a sequence in $\mathbb R$ is a non-convergent Cauchy-sequence in $((0,\infty),d_e)$ since $0 \notin (0,\infty)$. Thus also $(x_n) = (\exp^{-1}(\xi_n)) = (\ln \xi_n)$ is a non-convergent Cauchy-sequence in $(\mathbb R,d)$. In my example I took $\xi_n = e^{-n}$ which gives $x_n = -n$.

Comment: Okay, only one request: could you exhibit a Cauchy sequence with respect $d'$ which not converges, please? Forgive the bother.

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro See my update.

Comment: Sorry, but I do not understand completely the last inequality: precisely I did not understand why the inequality $$e^{-r}(e^{-n+r}+e^{-m+r})\le e^r$$ holds: then why this implies that
$$
d(x_h,x_k)\le\epsilon
$$
for any $h,k\ge r$?
Perhaps did you inted to wrote $$e^{-r}(e^{-n+r}+e^{-m+r})\le 2 e^{-r}$$
instead? Indeed for any $\epsilon\in\Bbb R^+$ there exists $n_0\in\Bbb N$ such that 
$$
e^{-n_0}\le\frac{\epsilon}2
$$
so that the inequality follows observing that
$$
e^l\le e^{n_0}
$$
for any $l\ge n_0$.

Comment: Moreover, since the exponential is continuous then for any $\epsilon\in\Bbb R^+$ there exists $\delta_\epsilon\in\Bbb R^+$ such that $$|e^x-e^y|<\epsilon$$ for any $y\in(x-\delta_\epsilon,x+\delta_\epsilon)$ which proves that $$(x-\delta_\epsilon,x+\delta_\epsilon)\subseteq B(x,\epsilon)$$ so that then inclusion $$\mathcal T_d\subseteq\mathcal T_e$$ holds. However now I am not able to prove the reverse inclusion. So could you explain better, please? Forgive my confusion.

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro Concerning $e^r$ you are right. For the other question see my update.

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro Oliver Diaz' answer uses the homeomorphism $\arctan : \mathbb R \to (-1,1)$.

Comment: Okay, all clear now: question upvoted and approved. Thanks very much for your assistance!!! See you soon...;-)

Comment: Hi professor, perhaps [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4555161/736008) I found an answer to a question I posed: could I ask your opinion about its correctness?

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro It is correct. See my answer.

Answer (score 3):

$\mathbb{R}$ is complete with respect to the metric $d(x,y)=|x-y|$ but not with respect to the metric $\rho(x,y)=|\arctan x-\arctan y|$. These metrics are equivalent in the sense that they yield the same topology on $\mathbb{R}$.
The sequence $x_n=n$ is not Cauchy with respect to $d$ but it is with respect to $\rho$. The completion of $\mathbb{R}$ w.r.t. $\rho$ is the extended real line $\mathbb{R}=\{-\infty,\infty\}\cup\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: So precisely $x_n=n$ is a not convergent Cauchy sequence with respect $\rho$, right?

Comment: Correct! The metrics are equivalent for they generate the same open sets. Thus if a sequence in the common space converges in $d$ then it also converges  in $\rho$ and viceversa.

Comment: Okay, I upvoted the question. Before to decided what to approve I would like to attend Paul's answer to my comment. Anyway thanks very much for your assistance!!!

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro: there is an interesting result that states that if $(X,d)$ is metric space, separable and $d$ is complete (such spaces are called Polish spaces), then any open set $U\subset X$ with the topology inherited from $X$ admits a metric that makes $U$ also a Polish space.

Comment: Oh, fantastic! And this can be "married" to my question?

Comment: Well this about your favorite Euclidean space, say $\mathbb{R}$ with the standard metric. Then $(0,1)$ admits a metric $d_0$ which is equivalent to the standard metric but under $d_0$, $(0,1)$ is complete: $d_0(x,y)=|x-y|+\Big|\frac{1}{\operatorname{dist}(x,(0,1)^c)}-frac{1}{\operatorname{dist}(y,(0,1)^c)}\Big|$

Comment: Oh, yeah: very fine!!!